# How to convert a plain string containing UTF-8 Data to

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, utf-8

I was working on a project and when I load the data returned by an API I receive UTF-8 encoded data in a string instead of a bytes object so I am unable to use the decode function to get a regular string

`"\x73\x61\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x20\x66\x6F\x72\x20\x64\x61\x74\x61"`

I get this instead of
`b"\x73\x61\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x20\x66\x6F\x72\x20\x64\x61\x74\x61"`

is there a way to convert the utf-8 string to a regular one!

Thank you gorgeous people :)

Comment: You might want to update the title to show your full question. Also, what code are you currently using to accomplish this?

Comment: what do you mean regular string, I think this is already a regular string.

Comment: In Python 3, strings _are_ UTF-8 data — so your question and incomplete title make little sense. Please [edit] your question and try to be clearer about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @martineau In Python 3, strings (`str`) are Unicode, but not UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
>>> x="\x73\x61\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x20\x66\x6F\x72\x20\x64\x61\x74\x61"
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> x
'sample for data'
>>> x.encode("utf-8")
b'sample for data'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your response is of type `bytes`, the following will print human-readable text:

```
response = b"\x73\x61\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x20\x66\x6F\x72\x20\x64\x61\x74\x61"
print(response.decode('utf-8')) # 'sample for data'
```